# dropdown value to db codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am working with CodeIgniter and have some problems with the database. I populate my dropdown list with customer names from table 'customers' in DB. I need to select the name from the dropdown, to input the name of the project and to add it to DB table 'projects', but in this table, I should have not the name of the customer, but its id. how can I implement it? And when I want to send not the id, but the name - I have an error: that customerName has NULL value.

> Here is my controller

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Add extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('url', 'form'));
        $this->load->model("addmodel");
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    private function view($page, $data=false) {
        $this->load->view("header.php", $data);
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
        $this->load->view("footer.php", $data);
        }

     public function add_project() { 
         $this->load->database();  
         $data['customers']=$this->addmodel->select_customer();  
         $this->view('add/add_project.php', $data);  

      }   
       public function new_project() {
      $this->load->database();  
      $data['customers']=$this->addmodel->select_customer(); 

      $this->load->view("add/add_project.php", $data);

      $projectName = $this->input->post("projectName");
      $customerID = $this->input->post("customerName");

      $this->addmodel->add_project($projectName, customerID); 

      redirect("add_project", "refresh");
      }
    }
```

> Here is my model

```
<?php
 class AddModel extends CI_Model {

  public function __construct() {

      $this->load->database();

  }

   function add_project($projectName, $customerID) {

  $this->db->insert('projects', array(
      'projectName' => $projectName,
      'customerID' => $customerID
  ));

  }

 function select_customer() {  
     $query = $this->db->get('customers');  
     return $query; 
  }  
   }
   ?>
```

> and, finally, here is my view

```
<?php echo form_open('new_project'); ?>


  <div id="form-main">
  <div id="form-div">
    <form class="form" id="form1">

     <select class="feedback-input" id="customer_selecter"> 
        <option name="customerName">Select customer</option>
        // <?php 
            foreach($customers->result() as $row){ 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->customerID.'">'.$row->customerName.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
      </select>

      <p class="projectName">
          <input type="text" name="projectName" placeholder="Project name" required class="feedback-input" id="projectName" />
      </p>


      <div class="submit">
          <button type="submit" id="button-red">Add</button>
      <div class="ease"></div>
          </form>   
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: your question is Lil confusing, What do you actually want to do?

Comment: `$this->addmodel->add_project($projectName, customerID);` should be `$this->addmodel->add_project($projectName, $customerID);` You forgot `$`

Comment: I want to send to db an ID of customer Name selected in dropdown

Comment: $ - it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Change option value to $row->customerName, so that you can get customer name

```
 <select class="feedback-input" id="customer_selecter" name="customerName> 
    // <?php 
        foreach($customers->result() as $row){ 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->customerID.'">'.$row->customerName.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: It's NULL again :(

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'customerID' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `projects` (`projectName`, `customerID`) VALUES ('name', NULL)

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/codeIgniter-3.1.5/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Answer (score 0):

Change your Html code select box name like this:

```
<select class="feedback-input" id="customer_selecter" name="customerName"> 
        <option >Select customer</option>
        // <?php 
        foreach($customers->result() as $row){ 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->customerID.'">'.$row->customerName.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

And need to pass corrct variable for customerId with `$` like this:

`$this->addmodel->add_project($projectName, $customerID);`

Comment: Thank u!! Now the name of project goes to db, but in customerID column the value is 0.

Comment: is your `customerID` field type is `int` @Ksenia?

Comment: You want to store your customer name or customer id  @Ksenia?

Comment: Now it's okay!!Thank u for your help!!!!
        <select class="feedback-input" id="customer_selecter" name="customerName"> 
        <option >Select customer</option>
         <?php 
        foreach($customers->result() as $row){ 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->customerID.'">'.$row->customerName.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>